# TOAD SQL - trying to get a count for two columns, with two different dates

Tags: sql, count, toad

Okay, I'm trying to come up with a head count report that looks at two different dates. This report would essentially count the number of active people that fit the column criteria.  The report works if I basically cut the script in half and run one date at a time. I'm trying to get an all in one script.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(EJOB1.EJBU, ' / ' ), Jobby1.EJDBU ),' ' ), (CASE WHEN CODE1.JB3 IN 'Y' THEN 'QBR' ELSE 'Non-QBR' END)) AS "BU / DBU START",
COUNT(CONCAT(CONCAT(Jobby1.EJBU, ' ' ), Jobby1.EJDBU)) AS "HC START",

CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(Jobby2.EJBU, ' / ' ), Jobby2.EJDBU ),' ' ), (CASE WHEN CODE2.JB3 IN 'Y' THEN 'QBR' ELSE 'Non-QBR' END)) AS "BU / DBU END",
COUNT(CONCAT(CONCAT(Jobby2.EJBU, ' ' ), Jobby2.EJDBU)) AS "HC END"

FROM Blah.SNARL SNARL1
JOIN Blah.Candy Candy1
ON SNARL1.EBFLXID = Candy1.EEFLXIDEB
JOIN Blah.Jobby Jobby1
ON SNARL1.EBFLXID = Jobby1.EJFLXIDEB
JOIN Blah.CODE CODE1
ON Jobby1.EJJOBCODE = JOBCODE1.JBJOBCODE,
Blah.SNARL SNARL2
JOIN Blah.Candy Candy2
ON SNARL2.EBFLXID = Candy2.EEFLXIDEB
JOIN Blah.Jobby Jobby2
ON SNARL2.EBFLXID = Jobby2.EJFLXIDEB
JOIN Blah.CODE CODE2
ON Jobby2.EJCODE = CODE2.JB

WHERE SNARL1.EBFLAGEMP = 'Y'
AND Candy1.EESTATUS != 'Terminated'
AND (Candy1.EEDATEBEG <= TO_DATE(:FROM_date, 'mm-dd-yyyy') 
AND (Candy1.EEDATEEND >= TO_DATE(:FROM_date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
OR Candy1.EEDATEEND IS NULL))
AND (Jobby1.EJDATEBEG <= TO_DATE(:FROM_date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
AND (Jobby1.EJDATEEND >= TO_DATE(:FROM_date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
OR Jobby1.EJDATEEND IS NULL))

AND SNARL2.EBFLAGEMP = 'Y'
AND Candy2.EESTATUS != 'Terminated'
AND (Candy2.EEDATEBEG <= TO_DATE(:TO_date, 'mm-dd-yyyy') 
AND (Candy2.EEDATEEND >= TO_DATE(:TO_date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
OR Candy2.EEDATEEND IS NULL))
AND (Jobby2.EJDATEBEG <= TO_DATE(:TO_date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
AND (Jobby2.EJDATEEND >= TO_DATE(:TO_date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
OR Jobby2.EJDATEEND IS NULL))
GROUP BY (Jobby1.EJBU,  Jobby1.EJDBU, CODE1.JB3),( Jobby2.EJBU,Jobby2.EJDBU, CODE2.JB3)
```

Comment: Your query really makes no sense.  I think you should go the route of providing sample data and the results that you want to see.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I'm looking for something that does this:

Comment: Start Column 1 | Column 2 (count) | End Column 3 | Column 4 (count) |
Finance | 25                        | Finance | 30 |

Comment: So basically, the first column says what the BU / DBU START name is, the second gives the amount of people in that BU/DBU at the start date.  The third column says what the BU/DBU end name is, the fourth column would give the amount of people in that BU/DBU at the end date.